# socket.io not working in Chrome

Tags: socket.io

i'm trying the this simple socket.io example and it works in Safari (send/receive from both sides). However, in the Chrome the client receives messages but the server won't receive messages sent by the client

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>web sockets</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    writeMessage(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});

function writeMessage(msg) {
    var msgArea = document.getElementById("msgArea");
    if (typeof msg == "object") {
        msgArea.innerHTML = msg.hello;
    }
    else {
        msgArea.innerHTML = msg;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="msgArea">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8888);

function handler (req, res) {

  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Am I missing something? Chrome is on v.19

Comment: are you sure about dev.intullect.com:8888 ? because i hosted the same app in my localhost and it seems to be working (in chrome)

Comment: yes...thats just a virtual host i have confirgured. i tried with localhost as well. it all works in safari...just not chrome

Comment: i should also add that it is not working in firefox v13 either.

Comment: What version of Socket.io do you use ? What transport is used on Chrome, Websocket ?

Comment: Did you try to remove "writeMessage(data);" ? Maybe the DOM isn't ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://socket.io-test.com to see if the problem is with your browser/proxy or your code.